# Mailtrap not working with Wordpress localhost (running on Xampp)

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp, localhost, mailtrap

I am trying to use Mailtrap to test emails sent from my localhost environment (Wordpress running on Xampp, Mac OS).

I implemented the code mailtrap gave me, into functions.php:

```
function mailtrap($phpmailer) {
  $phpmailer->isSMTP();
  $phpmailer->Host = 'smtp.mailtrap.io';
  $phpmailer->SMTPAuth = true;
  $phpmailer->Port = 2525;
  $phpmailer->Username = '***-cd4b';
  $phpmailer->Password = '***-239a';
}

add_action('phpmailer_init', 'mailtrap');
```

I made a php file where I try to send the email with this code:

```
   $to = "benviat@gmail.com";
   $subject = 'my subject';
   $message = 'I would like to work with you';
   $headers[] = 'From: Ben<bviatte@gmail.com>';

   $sent_message = wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers);
   var_dump($sent_message);
   if ( $sent_message ) {
       echo 'The test message was sent. Check your email inbox.';
   } else {
       echo 'The message was not sent';
   }
```

However, all I get is a "This message was not sent".

When I check the error logs, what I get is a:
AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down

as well as a:
AH01906: localhost:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!